# OpenGl - Progressive Radiosity - Scene gaining too much energy

Tags: opengl

I have developed a Radiosity program on OpenGl. The problem I am having is that the program is gaining energy somehow, the unshot radiosity becomes smaller at first, as it should as energy is being absorbed but then suddenly it starts growing back again!

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a typical issue of round-off errors. The usual approach is to keep account of the total energy contained in the scene, including any kind of dissipation (absorbtion, loss of light into unbound space and so on). To correct for any round-off errors you take the ratio of starting energy with the energy being "numerically" in the scene and multiply *all* energy contributions, which includes the dissipations, by this correction factor, to renormalize to the original amount of energy.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I find it hard to grasp the concept. Thank you!